# Reset password identity server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I was looking to implement a password reset option in my blazor application using ASP.NET Core hosted. I have done scaffolding giving me `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/....` I was looking to make a page with a form which could change the passwords and emails of users stored in AspNetUsers table. A lot of documentation uses SendGrid for email reset however I do not want to use email reset, instead I would like to make my own razor page where I can display a form for password/email reset. How might I go about resetting existing users email/passwords stored in AspNetUsers table? I am unsure if I need to utilise `ResetPasswordModel` and if I do, how I would implement it. Would appreciate any insight into this. Thanks in advance.

I have tried giving the `ResetPassword.cshtml` page a route to access the reset form but this produced a page showing `A code must be supplied for password reset.` I assume this is the incorrect approach

```
@page "/resetpassword"
@model ResetPasswordModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Reset password";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<h4>Reset your password.</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input asp-for="Input.Code" type="hidden" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: Did you customize a password reset page yourself?

Answer (score 1):

For this reset password logic, you are supposed to send a link by email to the user containing a code generated with [UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(TUser)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.generatepasswordresettokenasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Indeed, anyone can access your reset password page, the token is supposed to make sure only the user that received the link by email can reset the password.